# gitorious install won't login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, gitorious

I have installed a copy of Gitorious on my own server. Everything so far seems to be okay except the fact I can't login. Any attempt to login(with correct credentials), from multiple browsers, just throws me back to the main page. Logging in with wrong password will just clear password box. What could be causing this?

Comment: https://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue resolution here:
http://groups.google.com/group/gitorious/browse_thread/thread/e377597c0cd774b7

I had to change my host in config from localhost to my domain name.